# Система подписки telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Как реализовать систему платных подписок в telebot?
Мне нужно чтобы при покупке подписки дата конца подписки заносилась в бд, но как ее узнать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вставляйте, например, 31 декабря. дата ничем не хуже любой другой.

Comment: ну грубо говоря, как прибавить к текущей дате длительность самой подписки?